# How do I combine multiple rows when using select that are essentially the same data?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a database where there's a description text stored but the description text itself is broken up into separate rows based on the text itself.

For example:

```
|ID  |Row  |Text                  |
-----------------------------------
|1   |1    |The cat went to the st|
|1   |2    |ore and bought some ca|
|1   |3    |tnip.                 |
|2   |1    |The dog didn't like to|
|2   |2    |drink water.          |
|3   |1    |It's cold outside     |
```

How would I write a select query so that all of the rows in the `Text` column are combined into a single result based on the `ID` column and ordered according to the `Row` column?

Comment: Search for the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/149799/420156 - and for the ordering use `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple using [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select group_concat(txt order by roooow SEPARATOR '')
from story
group by id
order by roooow;
```

By the way, `row` and `text` are bad names for columns, as they are reserved keywords.

Comment: This did the trick, works great and thank you to the two people that commented. The row and text column names were just for the example :)

Comment: I am running into a quirk with GROUP_CONCAT(), it has a limit of 1024 characters and it truncates the rest without throwing an error. I needed to use SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000; to change this limit.